# How to stop ultimate members to redirect comment authors to user profile?

Tags: comments

I'm having a problem with the Ultimate Member plugin.

The comments author links get redirected to the user profile. I need the basic WP feature- pointing to author URL/website. The plugin is overriding the basic function.

I checked the "redirecting the author page" on the plugin option, but that option is for author-posts-permalink but not comment author website URL.

Now, how do I disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with actual version of Ultimate Member (2.0.21), you can do that with this filter :

```
add_filter("plugins_loaded", function () {

    remove_filter('get_comment_author_link', 'um_comment_link_to_profile', 10000, 3 );

}, 50);
```